# Creating a quiz model using BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

First time using BackboneJS, but I am a little stumped with creating a "Quiz" model along with  a "Round" model. The quiz keeps track of the score and such and a quiz has many rounds. The "Quiz" view creates a new "Quiz" model, and then it creates a new instance of a "Round" view. The "Round" view creates a new instance of a "Round" model. The user proceeds to fill out the information about the "Round" model in the "Round" view. Here's where the structural problem comes in. How should I keep track of the results?

The "Quiz" model has a score attribute, but the "Round" view is unable to access the attributes of the "Quiz" model unless it is directly passed in. If I did this, I would be passing the Quiz's score attribute to basically every view in the future. Is this fine? Or should I create a global score variable? Or, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Round` view shouldn't access `Quiz` model but `Round` could do this through some global events like this

```
var observatory = $({});
var quiz = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        observatory.bind('change_score', _.bind(this.changeScore, this))
    },

    changeScore: function(newScore) {
        this.set({
            score: newScore
        });
    }
});
var round = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click button': 'changeScore'
    },

    changeScore: function(event) {
        observatory.trigger('change_score', [event.currentTarget.value]);
    }
});
```

this code requires jquery

Comment: What is the significance of this line: var observatory = $({})

Comment: In jQuery it will create an empty jq object on which you can hang events

Comment: @egidra. 
$({}) is used to assign Jquery to an empty object which will be used as queue holder.
This is a fine answer with an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7134043/4373616